# summing multiple columns values which has different column names by using pattern matching of column names using pyspark/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

for example:
I have a dataframe with columns like

| lens | plain-prod 102 | plain-prod 105 | plain-prod 107 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| First | 3 | 7 | 2 |
| Second | 4 | 8 | 1 |

so i need to do a pattern matching (^plain-prod.*) and pick up all 3 columns matching that and create new column plain_sum having the sum how to achieve this using pyspark or pandas.

| lens | plain-prod 102 | plain-prod 105 | plain-prod 107 | plain_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 | 8 |
| Second | 2 | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| First | 3 | 7 | 2 | 12 |
| Second | 4 | 8 | 1 | 13 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach with Pandas (`df` is your data frame):

```
df['plain_sum'] = df.filter(regex='^plain-prod.*').sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"lens": "First", "plain-prod 102": 1, "plain-prod 105": 3, "plain-prod 107": 4},
    {"lens": "Second", "plain-prod 102": 2, "plain-prod 105": 3, "plain-prod 107": 4},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.withColumn(
    "plain_sum", sum([F.col(x) for x in df.columns if "plain-prod" in x])
)
```

Result:

```
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+                 
|lens  |plain-prod 102|plain-prod 105|plain-prod 107|plain_sum|
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|First |1             |3             |4             |8        |
|Second|2             |3             |4             |9        |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: this fails with a error Invalid argument, not a string or column

Comment: @Ajaykumar Please provide an example of the code you are running.

Comment: same code i ran just by chjanging dataframe name and filter

Comment: @Ajaykumar I guess your original dataset is different from my test example. Anyways, I've updated the answer, maybe that will help you if you need it.

Comment: did you execute your code in pyspark. if not try it once you'll get the error message for the example dataframe which you created

Comment: @Ajaykumar I did, and I don't get an error message. Pyspark version 3.1.2. Have you executed exactly what I gave as an example?

Comment: @Ajaykumar If you are using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` it will overwrite `sum` function and you will get `Invalid argument, not a string or column`. Try the exact code I wrote with the same import statements.

Comment: im using pysaprk version 3.0.1

Comment: i think because of that im getting this error /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:387: UserWarning: inferring schema from dict is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead
  warnings.warn("inferring schema from dict is deprecated,"
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [Column<b'plain-prod 102'>, Column<b'plain-prod 105'>, Column<b'plain-prod 107'>] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.